# Как реализовать загрузку сделанного снимка в firebase? Android java

Tags: java, android, изображения, firebase

Нужно реализовать приложение.
Вот суть:

-пользователь регистрируется ( auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mailText.getText().toString(), passText.getText().toString()))

-при регистрации у пользователя создаётся личная папка.

-В эту папку он потом может загружает изображения, и потом может посмотреть эти изображения.

-Он может просматривать содержимое папок других пользователей

Так вот, замкнулся на загрузке сделанного изображения в Firebase

Сейчас написано:
Регистрация и авторизация пользователя, добавление данных о пользователях в базу(имя, телефон)
Создание снимка и запись в ImageView

Подскажите как сделанный снимок загрузить в firebase. И дайте пару подсказок по дальнейшим действиям. Прошу вас, для меня это важно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте облачное хранилище Firebase Storage ([документация с официального сайта](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start)).
Для этого Вам нужно будет начать работу с хранилищем через консоль Firebase и настроить правила доступа.

Чтобы загрузить файл в облачное хранилище, Вы сначала создаете ссылку на путь к хранилищу (нужно будет импортировать `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'`).

```
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
```

Затем Вам нужно своё изображение преобразовать в байтовый массив. Если у Вас изображение в ImageView imageView, то это можно сделать так:

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
```

В итоге Вы получаете массив `data`, который можно записать в Firebase Storage.

```
UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.Child("переменная с названием папки текущего пользователя").putBytes(data);
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // если произошла ошибка
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // всё хорошо
 //данные можно получить из taskSnapshot.getMetadata() (метадата: размер файла, тип и т.д.)
    }
});
```

Готово - изображение загружено в хранилище в папку пользователя.

Дальше Вы можете читать свои файлы из хранилища. Несколько способов описаны [тут](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files) (в зависимости от того, в каком формате Вы хотите получить результат).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Буду рада, если поможет! Успехов!

Comment: Насть, а можешь помочь с отображением фото из firebase storage? Мне нужно что-то на подобии галереи. Вопрос висит у меня, очень важен твой совет, спасибо!

Comment: Обязательно напишу!

Comment: Спасибо! Если все получиться могу 500 руб переслать)

Comment: Телеграмм есть, что б связаться проще было?

Comment: Либо давай так, мне этот проект нужен очень, поэтому я могу прямо сразу заплатить 500,  а потом мы с тобой по зум свяжемся и решим проблему я тебе еще 500 доплачу.